# Can not use setContentView from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, setcontentview

I'm trying to change the layout of my Activity through AsyncTask.

In onPostExecute() I'm calling:

```
MyActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub);
```

but it wont let me, saying "MyActivity is not an enclosing class".

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Where do you call and implement the AsynkTask? You can give the AsyncTask the activity as callback and then call setContentView().

Comment: Maybe this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116415/mainactivity-this-is-not-an-enclosing-class-asynctask

Comment: It should work if you embed the AsyncTask class as an inner class of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't need the 'MyActivity.this.'; the below works for me:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return R.layout.activity_home;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        setContentView(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a wrong way to change layout in activity in rutime. If you want to show a screen with another layout you should use fragments or create another one activity and set there up your layout.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you embed the `AsyncTask` class as an inner class of the activity.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    ...
    public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ...> {

        @Override
        protected ... doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(... result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub);
        }
    }

}
```