# "...MovieDetail is not an enclosing class" error on Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an activity with two AsyncTasks defined. While building out a two pane tablet UI I moved a lot of the logic to a fragment class. The AsyncTasks are still in the original activity class. I am trying to instantiate and execute the tasks using the qualified names but get a `..is not an enclosing class` error. I am instantiating the tasks like so:

`MovieDetail.FetchTrailersTask fetchTrailersTask = new MovieDetail.FetchTrailersTask();`

I've also tried `getActivity.new [package_name].MovieDetail.FetchTrailersTask();`

This didn't work either.

Comment: you need to move `FetchTrailersTask` to your fragment.. It does not work like this..!! see this [MainActivity.this is not an enclosing class AsyncTask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116415/mainactivity-this-is-not-an-enclosing-class-asynctask).

Comment: @jankigadhiya Thanks - actually in the process of trying that right now! Working through how to gain access to the views I need which were previously available in the activity.

Comment: This doesn't relate to your question ? Is it ??

Comment: @jankigadhiya why vote the question down?

Comment: i have not downvoted.. If i was up to i will not suggest you the solution..!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by moving the AsyncTasks to the fragment class. I don't think there was a reason to, but in the event I wanted/needed to leave them in the activity class, I couldn't find a way to do so.